# Routing specific IP/block to VPN and the rest to net_gateway in OpenVPN

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn

VPN is working properly.

However, I wanted to route only a specific IP/block to `net_vpn` and all the rest of the traffic  to `net_gateway`.

```
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 net_gateway
route 10.8.1.0 255.255.0.0 vpn_gateway
```

I tried this, but I think it does not work.

Comment: Which OS? Keep in mind that routing on the reverse path must also set up correctly.  Debug your setup using a packet analyzer like tcpdump or wireshark.

Comment: Linux (Debian) Yeah. I only wanted to allow specific block, since that VPN is slow.

Comment: Have you done the packet analysis?